# Ruby, True/false regex

Tags: ruby, regex

So I've got an issue where my regex looks like this: `/true|false/`.

When I check the word `falsee` I get a true from this regex, is there a way to just limit it to the exact `true` or `false` words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/^(true|false)$/
```

It will match the beginning and end of the test string with `^` and `$`, respectively, so nothing else can be in the string (exact match).

See live example at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uL8yN6/1).

**UPDATE** (see @w0lf's comment): The parentheses are to isolate the `true|false` clause so that they are not grouped incorrectly. (This also puts the `true` or `false` match in the first capturing group, but since it seems that you are only matching and not capturing an output, this should not make a difference).

---

Alternatively, if you simply want to match two values, there are easier ways in Ruby. @SimoneCarletti suggests one. You can also use the basic `==` or `eql?` operators. Try running the following script to see that these all work:

```rb
values = ["true", "false", "almosttrue", "falsealmost"]
values.each do | value |
  puts value

  # these three are all equivalent
  puts "match with if" if value == "true" || value == "false"
  puts "match with equals?" if (value.eql? "true") || (value.eql? "false")
  puts "match with regex" if /^(true|false)$/.match value

  puts
end
```

Comment: That would also match `truely` and `something false`.

Comment: @w0lf Edited with explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: @AlCode I'm glad I helped you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `^` and `$` anchors:

```
/^(true|false)$/
```

**Edit:** As Cary pointed out in the comments, the pattern above will also match multiline strings that happen to contain a line with `true` or `false`. To avoid this, use the `\A` and `\z` delimiters that match the beginning and end of string respectively:

```
/\A(true|false)\z/
```

Comment: True, for strings consisting of a single line, you can use either the ends-of-line anchors (`^` and `$`) or the ends-of-string anchors (`\A` and `\z`). I suggest you use the latter whenever you are anchoring the ends of a string. By using `^` and `$` here you are perpetuating the mistaken belief held many Rubiests that they are ends-of-string anchors.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try out

```
/^(true|false)$/
```

where ^ is the start of a line and $ the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
/^(true|false)$/
```

or even better

```
/\A(true|false)\z/
```

that will match the beginning and end of the string (instead of line). If you only need to match for whose words, it may be more efficient to use a simple array and `include?`:

```
%w( true false ).include?(value)
```